# How to display and handle dynamic checkoxes that are dependent on Task array value in the backend (Mongodb) in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I working on a react project where I have requirement like,

I have array inside contain, 1 Object and 1 Array named `Task[]`

```
"contractor": [
                {
                  "contractGivenBy": -1,
                  "contractorID": 0,
                  "contractorName": "contractor1",
                  "reviewedByAssigner": false,
                  "submitReviewToAssigner": false,
                  "tasks": [ 2, 4, 6 ],
                  "tasksDone": false
                },
```

Now, I want to display the Tasks array as Checkboxes in the page.

That is nice, I displayed all checkboxes using `map()` method, But the problem is, How to handle (get values from those checkboxes) when user checked or unchecked the specific checkbox.

I'm using React functional component with React hooks.

Here is what is tried..

```html
   <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
      {               
         projectData.contractor[0].tasks.map((task, index) => {
              return (
                     <div style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>

                         <FormControlLabel
                             control={
                                 <Checkbox
                                    checked={false}
                                    value={task}
                                    onChange={handleTask} />
                                }
                                 label={`task ${task}`}
                                />
                              </div>
                             )
                           })
                          }
          <Button 
              type="submit" 
               style={{ 
                   backgroundColor:"rgba(25,123,189)", 
                   color: "white" 
                 }}>
            Assgin
          </Button>
    </form>
```

Comment: How many checkboxes could be displayed? and does `tasks: [2, 4, 6]` means checked box number?

Comment: For every element in the array, I want to display a checkbox and get the value of the checkbox, the value is eventually the array element itself.

Comment: okay, so what is the maximum checkbox? I mean, if there are `tasks: [2,4,6]`, there are 6 checkboxes or more? if the count is dynamic, how do you know the total count?

Comment: `tasks.length` method to know the tasks array length.

Comment: the `tasks` have only **checked** box number, isn't it? I believe you should display all checkboxes **even not checked**. Do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Here you go , it uses react hooks with checkbox implementation, i have tweaked it a little with `<input type />` but you will get the idea

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Checkbox = ({ type = "checkbox", name, checked = false, onChange }) => {
  console.log("Checkbox: ", name, checked);

  return (
    <input type={type} name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
  );
};

const CheckboxExample = () => {
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState({});

  const handleChange = event => {
    setCheckedItems({
      ...checkedItems,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
    });
    console.log("checkedItems: ", checkedItems);
  };

  const checkboxes = [
    {
      name: "check-box-1",
      key: "checkBox1",
      label: "Check Box 1"
    },
    {
      name: "check-box-2",
      key: "checkBox2",
      label: "Check Box 2"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <lable>Checked item name : {checkedItems["check-box-1"]} </lable> <br />
      {checkboxes.map(item => (
        <label key={item.key}>
          {item.name}
          <Checkbox
            name={item.name}
            checked={checkedItems[item.name]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CheckboxExample />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Yeah, i have tried that one, But `taskSet()` replaces the old values every time `handleTask()` called. That not the behavior i want. @raju

Comment: I have tried like this, First i will take an empty array at the top, For every checkbox i take the value and push to that empty array, like `onChange={(e) => data.push(e.target.value)}` . And after user submits, i stored that in state like this `const [checkboxData, setCheckboxData] = React.useState(data);
`

Comment: see this https://ibb.co/0QLKx3q image . i have used set() data structure to store unique check values and it does so

Comment: lemme check again

Comment: here see this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-xzvq5